# Как объединить ячейки в JTable?

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток!

Необходимо сделать такую таблицу

[image]

Но я не нашел никакого способа объединить ячейки для `JTable`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: наверно проще будет сделать 2 таблицы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал таблицы в HTML